# jquery accordion menu

Tags: jquery, show-hide, jquery-ui-accordion

if say I want to make an accordion menu such like this:

```
    <div class="blueheaderbar" style="margin-top:20px; cursor:pointer;">

                <div class="floatleft">euuei slks</div>
                <div class="floatright"><input class="showhidebtn" type="button" value="Show Outlet" style="margin:6px 16px 0 0; width:86px" /></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordionContent" style="padding-left:8px;">
                Content 1
            </div>

   <div class="blueheaderbar selected" style="margin-top:20px; cursor:pointer;">

                <div class="floatleft">title 2</div>
                <div class="floatright"><input class="showhidebtn" type="button" value="Show Outlet" style="margin:6px 16px 0 0; width:86px" /></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordionContent" style="padding-left:8px;">
                Content 2 
            </div>
```

When user onclick the button selected content just show. how do I modify the below query code work?

I know ".next()" must be the key problem which make this cannot work, hope expert could help

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
jQuery('.accordionButton').click(function() {


    jQuery('.showhidebtn').attr('value', 'Show Outlet');


    jQuery('.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');


    if(jQuery(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {


        jQuery(this).attr('value', 'Hide Outlet');


        jQuery(this).next().slideDown('normal');
     } 

 });

jQuery('.accordionContent').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

If this fits your need,  you should look at [jQuery Accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) and [its demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/).

Comment: nope. That is not I want because I want make it only the button click the content just can be show.